# Gerar arquivo txt com hora atual atualizada a cada segundo com php e ajax

Tags: php

Possuo na empresa um software desktop que recebe informações de arquivos de texto (txt) gerados por uma página web em `php`. Preciso porém, fazer com que o software leia (em tempo real) a data e a hora do sistema, sendo que cada informação deve ser gerada em um arquivo diferente. Consegui através do `php` gerar a data e a hora de acordo com o clique de um botão na página, mas precisava que a hora fosse atualizada em tempo real para que o programa possa exibir corretamente.
Existe alguma função que passe e atualize um arquivo txt com a hora atual? Podemos utilizar `php`, `js`, `ajax`, `jquery` ou qualquer outra alternativa.
Outra opção seria a criação de um arquivo `xml` que receberia, em tempo real, a hora atual do sistema, mas não faço noção de como fazer isso.

Segue o código utilizado para gravar a data e hora nos arquivos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Gestão para OBS</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Data" name="btnBotao"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Hora" name="btnBotao">
        </form>
    </body>

    <?php
        $botao = $_POST["btnBotao"];
        switch($botao)
        {
            case 'Data':
                date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
                $data = date("d/m/Y");
                $arquivo_data = "Data.txt";
                $fo = fopen($arquivo_data, "w+");
                fwrite($fo, $data);
                fclose($fo);
                break;

            case 'Hora':
                date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
                $hora = date("H:i");
                $arquivo_hora = "Hora.txt";
                $fo = fopen($arquivo_hora, "w+");
                fwrite($fo, $hora);
                fclose($fo);
                break;              
        }
    ?>
</html>
```

O programa gera os arquivos `Data.txt` e `Hora.txt`, mas a hora precisa ser atualizada em tempo real.

Comment: Acho que sua pergunta ficou um pouco confusa, você quer ficar atualizando um arquivo txt a cada segundo ou quer que no lugar dos seus inupts pegue a data e hora no momento do clique do botão?

Comment: O seu `input` de data e hora estão com o mesmo `name`, então o programa nunca vai entrar na seção `Hora` do seu `case`.

Comment: Utilize `setInterval` (js), mas o PHP não é a melhor solução. Talvez o NodeJs seja melhor para seu caso.

Comment: Exatamente Leandro. O que preciso é que um arquivo txt fique sendo atualizado segundo a segundo com a hora atual.

Comment: Valdeir, vou dar uma olhada no NodeJs. Nunca trabalhei com ele mas vou verificar. Obrigado

Comment: Procure sobre agendador de tarefas, não é necessário trocar de tecnologia para fazer isso. Se o seu servidor for `windows`, a ferramenta se chama realmente `Agendador de Tarefas`. Se for `linux` essa ferramenta é o `cron`. Você agenda um script para rodar de tempo em tempo.

Comment: Roberto, o problema de usar o agendador de tarefas ou o cron é que ele é específico de plataforma. O nosso software roda tanto em ambiente Windows como Linux, e usando uma página web para realizar a geração dos arquivos, todas as estações poderiam acessar o caminho do arquivo que fica em nosso servidor para utilizar a data e hora no software. Por isso precisamos de algo que funcione via web, seja em php, javascript, c#, jquery ou qualquer outra sugestão.